# Google Chrome won't update CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I just started working on a Wordpress theme, but it won't reload the stylesheet after I update. I searched throughout here and tried the common remedies, including:

- Reload holding ctrl/shift
- Reload while Developer Tools is open
- Reload twice quickly in a row
- Get firefox/firebug
- Add the timestamp generator to the end of the href
- Install an extension, specifically this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog\

It seems like it only reloads every once in a while, and it really impedes my ability to write CSS...

Does anyone here have any ideas to fix this?

Thanks.

edit: I think it may have something to do with my host (it's free). I'm just going to move offline for development, I think.

Comment: The problem is not with the browser. You probably have some sort of caching extension in Wordpress itself.

Comment: Overly aggressive server caching? You can inspect the file request in chrome and see what the server responds with. If its a 304, the server is telling the client that nothing has changed. You can defeat that by adding a random number to a get request in your css url. For instance: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" url="style.css?r=<?php echo microtime(); ?>" />` Your page would have to be a .php page for that example.

Answer (score 5):

You can always go into `Incognito` which does not use any chached data. It also does not save any history information.

[image: Incognito Mode]

To use it you can press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> then navigate to the page / website that you want to see.

You can also access Incognito by pressing the `☰` icon in the top right of your chrome window and click on `New incognito window`:

[image: Incognito Mode from Hamburger Menu]

If your page is still not updating I would make sure that the file is even being saved. Because at this point your issue would not be because of files being cached..

My only other thought is that it could be your CSS itself... Sometimes your CSS is not applied due to an error in your code, another piece of code counteracting it, etc...

So see what is being applied:

press <kbd>F12</kbd>

OR

right click somewhere on your page and press `Inspect Element`.

You should see something like this (except with your code / webpage):

[image: Sample Inspect Elements]

The parts of the "Inspect Element" will be sized slightly different but you can change those around...

Essentially click on the html element that you are trying to change the css on...

You will now see what css elements are being displayed... If they are crossed out, it most likely means that there is some other parent (or just some other property) that is canceling out the css you are adding.

These are just some of the reasons why the CSS may not be working! But I hope this helps!

Comment: Even though your answer is right, after all the things the OP did I *highly* doubt client-side caching is the issue here.

Comment: In my case, this is what solved all my problems. Chrome kept caching my one AND ONLY css file, and it refused to update. Moved to incognito mode, and problem solved. Stupid fix, but it works. FYI, using Chrome 60 more than a year and a half after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

When working with child theme, make sure you are loading the right css file. Sometimes you load the parent's css file.

Make sure to disable cache plugin in development time.